# Find long running EF SQL statement and matching to c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've been using EF5 is an application for a while now but recently the live application has been timing out with SQL time out errors.  I've run the following command to find long running SQL statements on the server in an attempt to locate the issue.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1, ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT) ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

This has given me a few leads but the sql statements that have been highlighted are clearly generated by EF is there anyway to find out where in my c# code the particular SQL statement was generated? For example this is a query that is taking a long time to run:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[CaseEventID] AS [CaseEventID],
    [Extent1].[CaseID] AS [CaseID],
    [Extent1].[EventDate] AS [EventDate],
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description],
    [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username],
    [Extent1].[OriginalID] AS [OriginalID],
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted],
    [Extent1].[ActualUsername] AS [ActualUsername]
FROM
    [dbo].[CaseEvents] AS [Extent1]
WHERE
    [Extent1].[CaseID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

The web page returns the error:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
SQL exception 0x80131904

Comment: If searching by primary key takes too long time, then problem isn't in EF. How are you going to optimize query above?

Comment: As @Dennis mentioned, with such a simple query, the problem is either the lack of indexing on the `CaseEvents` table, or, if it's a view, general lack of appropriate indexes. Check the query's execution plan and use the Data Tuning Advisor to find missing indexes.

Comment: Such a simple query shouldn't ever cause a timeout. *What* timeout is this? Connection timeout, command timeout? Are you using long-running transactions that block you from reading the data? Use SQL Server's Profiler and Activity Monitor to see what else is running at the same time and check what blocks your query

Comment: Are you using transactions at all in your code and why? Given that `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally, you shouldn't need to open transactions just to store changes. If you use transactions to "prevent" others from modifying "opened" records, you are using them in the wrong way

Comment: Good point an index was missing on that table, which I've now resolved however i didn't think i was using that table in my code so i'd like to know where its called if there is a way of matching up the SQL to the EF call. Also that was just the first example statement. I'm not using transactions.